# Combo question: urborg tomb of yawgmoth, torpor orb, kormus bell, dark depths = free Marit Lage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have the following in play:

- [Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urborg%2C%20Tomb%20of%20Yawgmoth)

> Each land is a Swamp in addition to its other land types.

- [Kormus Bell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kormus%20Bell)

> All Swamps are 1/1 black creatures that are still lands.

- [Torpor Orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Torpor%20Orb)

> Creatures entering the battlefield don't cause abilities to trigger.

And I play [Dark Depths](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Depths):

> Dark Depths enters the battlefield with ten ice counters on it.

> {3}: Remove an ice counter from Dark Depths.

> When Dark Depths has no ice counters on it, sacrifice it. If you do, put a legendary 20/20 black Avatar creature token with flying and indestructible named Marit Lage onto the battlefield.

What I am hoping happens is: The Urborg makes my Dark Depths also a swamp, so Kormus Bell makes it a creature, so then Torpor Orb makes its comes into play ability not trigger, so the Dark Depths will not enter play with any counters, allowing me to immediately sacrifice for 20/20 Marit Lage. Any reason that would not work?

Comment: "Dark Depths enters the battlefield with ten ice counters on it." is equivalent to "As Dark Depths enters the battlefield, place ten ice counters on it." It's a static ability that creates a replacement effect that redefines what it means for this card to be moved to the battlefield.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It won't work.  Dark Depths' "Dark Depths enters the battlefield with ten ice counters on it." ability is not a triggered ability; you can tell because it doesn't use the words "when," "whenever," or "at," which are part of the definition of "triggered ability" in the Comprehensive Rules:

> 112.3c Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as "[Trigger condition], [effect]," and include (and usually begin with) the word "when," "whenever," or "at." Whenever the trigger event occurs, the ability is put on the stack the next time a player would receive priority and stays there until it’s countered, it resolves, or it otherwise leaves the stack. See rule 603, "Handling Triggered Abilities."

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as "[Trigger condition], [effect]," and begin with the word "when," "whenever," or "at." They can also be expressed as "[When/Whenever/At] [trigger event], [effect]."

Instead, the ability is just a plain old static ability (specifically, a replacement ability, but that doesn't matter here).  Thus, Torpor Orb won't stop the ice counters from being placed on your Legendary Snow Creature Land — Swamp, and your combo won't work.

Stick with [Vampire Hexmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vampire%20Hexmage).

Comment: Or Thespian's Stage.

Comment: haven't seen Thespian's Stage before, that card is sweet!